# Connect event/action to QPlainTextEdit

Tags: c++, qt

I have a `QTabWidget` which contains a QPlainTextEdit. I have managed to add action to the QTabWidget so that whenever a new tab opens, a new QPlainTextEdit is also added in the new tab. See code.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QPlainTextEdit>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QAction>
#include <QTextCursor>
#include <iostream>
#include <QKeyEvent>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    setWindowTitle("Tilde");
    current_tab = 1;
    on_action_New_triggered();
    ui->tabWidget->setTabsClosable(true);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_action_New_triggered()
{
    QString newTab = "Tab " + QString::number(current_tab);
    ui->tabWidget->addTab(new QPlainTextEdit, newTab);
    ui->tabWidget->setCurrentIndex(current_tab - 1);
    current_tab++;
    editor = qobject_cast<QPlainTextEdit *>(ui->tabWidget->currentWidget());
    editor->setFocus();
    /*connect(editor->document(), SIGNAL(cursorPositionChanged(QTextCursor)),
            this, SLOT(on_editor_cursorPositionChanged()));*/
}

void MainWindow::on_actionNew_document_triggered()
{
    on_action_New_triggered();
}

void MainWindow::on_action_Exit_triggered()
{
    QMessageBox msg;
    msg.addButton(QMessageBox::Yes);
    msg.addButton(QMessageBox::No);
    msg.setText("Exit program?");

    int selection = msg.exec();

    if (selection == QMessageBox::Yes)
        qApp->exit(0);
}

// highlight current line
void MainWindow::on_editor_cursorPositionChanged()
{
    QTextEdit::ExtraSelection highlight;
    highlight.cursor = editor->textCursor();
    highlight.format.setProperty(QTextFormat::FullWidthSelection, true);
    highlight.format.setBackground( QColor(240, 246, 217) );

    QList<QTextEdit::ExtraSelection> extras;
    extras << highlight;
    editor->setExtraSelections(extras);
}
```

The commented code gives compiler error:

> QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for
>   on_editor_cursorPositionChanged()

I have added the function in the header file.

Header file:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QPlainTextEdit>
#include <QTextCursor>

namespace Ui
{
    class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_action_New_triggered();
    void on_actionNew_document_triggered();
    void on_action_Exit_triggered();
    void on_editor_cursorPositionChanged();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QPlainTextEdit *editor;
    qint8 current_tab;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Comment: Yes, it is defined under private slots in the header file.

Comment: Is that commented out `connect` the actual line that is causing the error or just a reference?

Comment: I have not edited the post with complete code. I guess the commented line causes the error. I can still run the application though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be that your signature for the SLOT is wrong?

```
/*connect(editor->document(), SIGNAL(cursorPositionChanged(QTextCursor)),
            this, SLOT(on_editor_cursorPositionChanged()));*/
```

Should be?

```
connect(editor->document(), SIGNAL(cursorPositionChanged(QTextCursor)),
            this, SLOT(on_editor_cursorPositionChanged(QTextCursor)));
```

Also, the naming convention you are using for that slot might be conflicting here with your manual connection. Qt may be trying to use the `connectSlotsByName` mechanism on your SLOT by matching the name:  `on_<member>_<signal>`

In this case, the current signature of that SLOT `on_editor_cursorPositionChanged()` would match with the QPlainTextEdit `editor` member. And then you are manually connecting the document to it with the wrong signature. You probably should create another slot that is named more normally `docCursorPosChanged(QTextCursor)`

Comment: The only valid choice I get from Qt Creator is cursorPositionChanged(QTextCursor)...

Comment: @raze: I actually misread your connection. I see you are connecting the document and not the editor. I just updated. Its probably the SLOT signature that is wrong.

Comment: I changed the slot name to `onEditorCursorPositionChanged()` and it magically worked. Thanks man!